# Create event handler is not called. Extending jQueryUI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget, extend

declare

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget('my.popup', $.ui.dialog, {
        'create': function (event, ui) {
            // this one is NOT called
            console.debug('create');
        },
        '_create': function () {
            // OK
            console.debug('_create');

           return this._super();
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

call

```
var div = jQuery('<div>').appendTo('body');
div.on('widgetcreate', function (event, ui) {
    // this one is NOT called
    console.debug('widgetcreate');
});
div.on('popupcreate', function (event, ui) {
    // OK
    console.debug('popupcreate');
});
div.popup();
```

I can understand why 'widgetcreate' does not work, but 'create' in options?
jQuery.Widget has *create* (http://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#event-create) and I guess dialog should inherit it and fire it internally with proper new name.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation which you link to is documenting a `create` event, not a function.

That being said, I'm not sure why http://jsfiddle.net/pranacoder/59qy9/ works with "create" instead of "_create" unless it is a version issue.